# Android cancel action pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns

In different Google aplications for Android, such as Gmail, Chrome, Now, etc. after deleting, closing or other action there is toast or bottom bar with cancel button. But there is no information about this action anywhere. Is there any library or pattern to do that? It seems hard to delete item from recyclerview but keep in database, show bar, on cancel return it to the same position, or delete it when bar hides.

Comment: You should use this method. `Handler handlerTimer = new Handler();handlerTimer.postDelayed(deleteRunnable, 20000);`

Comment: and this to remove it on cancel click. `handlerTimer.removeCallbacks(deleteRunnable);`